# In how many ways can Samantha attend six of ten meetings if she cannot skip three meetings in a row?

Tags: combinatorics

Samantha plans to attend exactly 6 out of 10 meetings. If she cannot skip three meetings in a row, how many possible ways are there to attend the meetings?
_____ways

$10C6- 4!.6.5.4= 2160$

$4!.6.5.4$ means there are $3$ meeting is $1 +$ other $3$ meetings so $4$, but there are $4$ arrangements in permutation, the three meetings are $6 \times 5 \times 4$, choosing from $6$ meetings .

Am I right?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain your reasoning.  I assume you are trying to subtract the number of ways Samantha could skip three meetings in a row from the number of ways she could attend six of the ten meetings.  However, it is not clear how you arrived at $4! \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$.

Comment: 4! .6.5.4 means there 3 meeting is 1 + other 3 meetings so 4 , but there are 4 arrangement in permutation , the three meetings are 6 x 5 x 4, choosing from 6 meetings . am i right?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect.  In fact, it is negative since you correctly used combinations to select the number of ways she could select six of the ten meetings but used permutations to subtract the cases in which she skips at least three meetings in a row.

She could select six of the ten meetings to attend in
$$\binom{10}{6}$$
ways.  Note that
$$\binom{10}{6} = \frac{10!}{6!4!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6!}{6! \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 10 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 = 210$$
What you calculated was 
$$P(10, 4) = \frac{10!}{(10 - 4)!} = \frac{10!}{6!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6!}{6!} = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 5040$$
which is the number of arranging six meetings.  However, the meetings occur in a set order, so we do not need to arrange them.

---

Notice that the number of ways Samantha can select six out of the ten meetings is equal to the number of ways of arranging six green and four black balls in a row.  The restriction that she cannot skip three meetings in a row means that there can be at most two consecutive black balls.

**Method 1:**  Place six green balls in a row.  This creates seven spaces in which we can place the black balls.

[image: attended_meetings]

We can express $4$ as a sum of positive integers not greater than $2$ in three ways:
\begin{align*}
4 & = 2 + 2\\
  & = 2 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
\end{align*}
They correspond, respectively, to the ways that Samantha can skip two meetings in a row twice, skip two meetings in a row once and skip a single meeting twice, skip a single meeting four times.

*Samantha skips two meetings in a row twice*:  Arrange the six green balls in a row, which creates the seven spaces indicated above.  We must insert two black balls in two of the seven spaces, which can be done in 
$$\binom{7}{2}$$
ways.  For instance, if we place them in the third and sixth spaces, we obtain the arrangement shown below.

[image: skips_two_meetings_in_a_row_twice]
Notice that such a choice prevents more that two black balls from being consecutive, that is, prevents Samantha from missing more than two consecutive meetings.  We now number the balls from left to right.  The numbers we place on the green balls represent the meetings Samantha attends; the number we place on the black balls represent the meetings she misses.

*Samantha skips two meetings in a row once and skips a single meeting twice*: Arrange the six green balls in a row, which creates the seven spaces indicated above.  Choose one of the seven spaces in which to insert two black balls and two of the remaining six spaces in which to insert one black ball.  For instance, if we choose the fifth space for the two black balls and the sixth and seventh spaces for the single black balls, we obtain the arrangement shown below.

[image: skips_two_meetings_in_a_row_once_and_a_single_meeting_twice]

There are 
$$\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2}$$ 
such selections.  Once the selections have been made, we number the balls from left to right.  As above, the numbers we place on the green balls represent the meetings Samantha attends; the number we place on the black balls represent the meetings she misses.

*Samantha skips a single meeting four times*:  Arrange the six green balls in a row, which creates the seven spaces indicated above.  Choose four of the seven spaces in which to place a black ball, which can be done in
$$\binom{7}{4}$$ 
ways.  For instance, if we choose the second, fourth, sixth, and seventh spaces, we obtain the arrangement shown below.

[image: skips_a_single_meeting_four_times]

Once the selections have been made, we number the balls from left to right.  As above, the numbers we place on the green balls represent the meetings Samantha attends; the number we place on the black balls represent the meetings she misses.

*Total:*  The number of ways Samantha can attend six of the ten meetings so that she never skips three meetings in a row is
$$\binom{7}{2} + \binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2} + \binom{7}{4} = 21 + 7 \cdot 15 + 35 = 161$$

**Method 2:** We subtract the number of ways Samantha could miss at least three consecutive meetings from the number of ways she could select six of the ten meetings to attend.

If Samantha were to skip three meetings in a row, the first of those meetings would have to occur in one of the first eight positions.  She could then select the other meeting to skip in seven ways (since three of the ten positions have been filled with skipped meetings).

However, if we subtract $8 \cdot 7$ from $\binom{10}{4}$, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted each of the seven ways Samantha could have skipped four consecutive meetings twice, once when we designated the first three of those four skipped meetings as the three consecutive meetings she skips and once when we designated the last three of those four skipped meetings as the three consecutive meetings she skips.  We should only subtract those seven ways Samantha could have skipped four consecutive meetings once, so we must add them back.

The reason there are seven ways Samantha could have skipped four consecutive meetings is that the first of those meetings must occur in the first seven of the ten meetings.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways Samantha could attend six of the ten meetings without skipping three meetings in a row is 
$$\binom{10}{4} - 8 \cdot 7 + 7 = 210 - 56 + 7 = 161$$

Comment: thankyou so much for very detail answer and explanation. I'm still trying to understand your answer, for method 2 why do you substract 8.7? is 8 means that 6 green+3 meeting but count as 1 + 1 meeting ? and why is it times 7?

Comment: Since there are a total of ten meetings, there are $8$ possible starting positions for a block of three consecutive skipped meetings.  That leaves $7$ choices for the position of the other skipped meeting.  That gives a preliminary count of $8 \cdot 7$ ways to skip four of the ten meetings if three of those meetings are consecutive.  However, as I indicated in my answer, that count is not quite right since we have counted the seven ways in which all four skipped meetings are consecutive twice, which is why I had to add $7$ after subtracting $8 \cdot 7$.